# else statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This code wont run as the last "else" statement near the bottom of the code which executes the code {console.log("invalid"} returns an error in the console in google chrome and I don't know how to fix it. When I execute the same app in ruby and I run it in the ruby terminal it works fine but for some reason in JavaScript it doesn't work.

```
var contacts = [
    {
    Name: "Scott McMahon",
    Contact: "04158656",
    Email: "scotttt@y7mail.com",
    Address: "3 rrhfh, vic 30555",
    }
];

var user_interface = () => {
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    console.log("These are your options")
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    console.log("1: Add a contact")
    console.log("2: Remove a contact")
    console.log("3: View contacts")
    console.log("4: EXIT")
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    let input = prompt("What would you like to do?")
    return input;
};

var user_input = user_interface()

while (user_input != 4 && user_input.toUpperCase() != "EXIT") {

    if (user_input == 1 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "ADD A CONTACT") {
        let addName = prompt("Please enter the name of the person you would like to add")
        let addNumber = prompt("What is the number you would like to add?")
        let addEmail = prompt("What is the persons email address?")
        let addAddress = prompt("What is this persons address?")

        let person_to_add = {
            Name: addName,
            Contact: addNumber,
            Email: addEmail,
            Address: addAddress,
        }

        contacts.push(person_to_add)

    } else if (user_input == 2 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "REMOVE A CONTACT") {
        
        for (person of contacts) {
            console.log(person.Name)
        } 
    
        let name = prompt("Which contact would you like to remove?")

        let index = 0
        for (person of contacts) {
            if (person.Name.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {
            contacts.splice(index, 1)
            }
            index += 1
            } else {
               console.log("invalid")
                    }
            
    } else if (user_input == 3 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "VIEW CONTACTS") {
        for (person of contacts) {
        console.log(person.Name)
        }
    }
    var user_input = user_interface()
};
```

Comment: "returns an error" - writing the error description would help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! Could you please add information about that error you get in the console? This will help us answer you.

Comment: It appears like you have one "}" too much.

Comment: To elaborate: "for (person of contacts) { if (...) { ... } **index += 1 }** { else ...", this isn't syntactically sound.

Comment: @Nicolas, the code throws following error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else'

Comment: I need the "invalid" statement to be loged only once when deleting a name that isnt already in the array. The first 2 solutions I was given dont work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's a problem in your for loop, it should be as follows:

```
        for (person of contacts) {
        if (person.Name.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {
            contacts.splice(index, 1)
            index += 1
        } else {
            console.log("invalid")
        }
    }
```

So the actual working code would be as follows:

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        Name: "Scott McMahon",
        Contact: "04158656",
        Email: "scotttt@y7mail.com",
        Address: "3 rrhfh, vic 30555",
    }
];

var user_interface = () => {
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    console.log("These are your options")
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    console.log("1: Add a contact")
    console.log("2: Remove a contact")
    console.log("3: View contacts")
    console.log("4: EXIT")
    console.log("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    let input = prompt("What would you like to do?")
    return input;
};

var user_input = user_interface()

while (user_input != 4 && user_input.toUpperCase() != "EXIT") {

    if (user_input == 1 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "ADD A CONTACT") {
        let addName = prompt("Please enter the name of the person you would like to add")
        let addNumber = prompt("What is the number you would like to add?")
        let addEmail = prompt("What is the persons email address?")
        let addAddress = prompt("What is this persons address?")

        let person_to_add = {
            Name: addName,
            Contact: addNumber,
            Email: addEmail,
            Address: addAddress,
        }

        contacts.push(person_to_add)

    } else if (user_input == 2 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "REMOVE A CONTACT") {

        for (person of contacts) {
            console.log(person.Name)
        }

        let name = prompt("Which contact would you like to remove?")

        let index = 0
        for (person of contacts) {
            if (person.Name.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {
                contacts.splice(index, 1)
                index += 1
            } else {
                console.log("invalid")
            }
        } 

    } else if (user_input == 3 || user_input.toUpperCase() == "VIEW CONTACTS") {
        for (person of contacts) {
            console.log(person.Name)
        }
    }
    var user_input = user_interface()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a } out of place, it's the one before your else {} block begins.

```
    for (person of contacts) {
        if (person.Name.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {
            contacts.splice(index, 1)
            index += 1
        } else {
            console.log("invalid")
        }
    }
```

Should become:

```
for (person of contacts) {
        if (person.Name.toUpperCase() == name.toUpperCase()) {
            contacts.splice(index, 1)
        }
        index += 1
        else {
           console.log("invalid")
        }
    }
```

Itwas actually closing off your for-loop, so there's just an else statement floating out in space without a corresponding **if**, causing your error.

Comment: Could you please rewrite it as it should look because the asteris and arow is confusing me?

Comment: I just updated it with before/after code. I don't know where your "index += 1" needs to be, though (in the if or in the else)

Comment: using your code if I enter an incorect name when deleting a person from the contacts list it logs "invalid" several times for every other name that wasnt entered. It should only appear once.

Comment: basically all i need to achieve is that when I enter a name to delete from the array, if the name is not in there then I want "invalid" to be executed.